# Using stringpos to find a string that has a newline on both side not working properly

Tags: php

I have this code to search for a string that its both sides has newline but it's not working properly

```
$pospoint = strpos($pdftxt, "\n{$stockcode}\n");
```

It cant find the string if i used above code. Is there other way around this?

Comment: What kind of newlines are in `$pdftxt`? Are you sure they are a single `"\n"`?

Comment: Try `PHP_EOL` that might work

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes it's just single "\n"

Comment: @Andreas i'll try this one

Comment: So it's not the newline, how about case, try `stripos()`.

Comment: wow PHP_EOL.$stockcode.PHP_EOL works. amazing. Thanks @Andreas

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the constant PHP_EOL instead of `"\n"`.
PHP_EOL (End Of Line) will choose what method the string uses as new line (`\n`, `\r\n`) so it's more dynamic than just guessing if it's `\n` or `\r\n`

```
$pospoint = strpos($pdftxt, PHP_EOL.$stockcode.PHP_EOL);
```